# Error al enviar archivos con Fetch en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, fetch

Quiero enviar un archivo al servidor por medio de `fetch`, pero cuando lo envió el campo file aparece vació al momento de enviarlo

```
 <body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" id="form" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="fileN">
    <button type="submit" id="btn">Enviar</button>
</form>

<script>
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    let formulario = document.getElementById("form")

    formulario.addEventListener("submit", function name(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault()

        let url = "http://localhost/WEBQUEST/Modulo1/Backend/public/index.php/api/works"
        let fileN = document.getElementById('fileN')

        let data1 = {
            "id": 2,
            "tarea": fileN.files[0],
            "estudiante": 1
        }

        fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(data1),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        }).then(response => response.text())
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
            }).catch(error => console.log(error))
    })
</script>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error no es de la [API fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch) , más bien es del método [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify) ya que no es posible convertir el Objeto de tipo File.

En su lugar podría recurrir a objetos [formData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData) para subir archivos y demás datos, eso sí, sería necesario eliminar `Content-Type` de la petición, caso contrario ignoraría los archivos subidos.

El código de envío quedaría de la siguiente forma.

```
let token = localStorage.getItem('token')
let formulario = document.getElementById("form")
formulario.addEventListener("submit", function name(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault()
    let url = "http://localhost/WEBQUEST/Modulo1/Backend/public/index.php/api/works"
    let fileN = document.getElementById('fileN')
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("id", 2);
    formData.append("tarea", fileN.files[0]);
    formData.append("estudiante", 1);
    fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
        headers: {
            //'Content-Type': '"multipart/form-data;',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    }).then(response => response.text())
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
    }).catch(error => console.log(error))
})
```

Desde PHP recuperaría los valores así

```
$_FILES['tarea'];
$_POST['estudiante'];
```

Comment: Si me funciono Gracias

Comment: como se obtienen esos datos, en un controlador en laravel 5.8 y como se hace para guardarlos.