# Envio de archivos pdf react nodejs

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, fetch, formdata

Mi primer proyecto web,

necesito subir archivos, mi backend esta en nodejs y uso express-fileupload no por alguna razón particular. El backend en postman funciona, pero no en mi interfaz. He intentado con ejemplos de axios, obteniendo Error Network, no pude solucionarlo... he encontrado información sobre react con clases, y no le entiendo... sineramente.

He actuado ciegamente acorde a mi lógica y los console log que recibo, pero siento estar totalmente perdido. Mi inteción es aprender, no que me resuevan el problema. He revisado la documentación de Mozilla para la interfaz FormData que hereda de Files, he buscado como constuir un Blob, sin éxito... honestamente no tengo idea que sigue...

Un salvavidas me ayudaría muchisimo.

Gracias millones

Si me permites, abajo el código:

Vista:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { documentAddNew } from '../actions/documents';
//import { useForm } from '../hooks/useForm'

export const UploadFiles = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();


    const [archivos, setArchivos] = useState(null);

    //const {archivo} = archivo;

    const subirArchivos = (e) =>{
        setArchivos(e);
    }
    const insertarArchivos = async(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        for (let index = 0; index < archivos.length; index++){
            formData.append("archivo", archivos[index]);
            //console.log(formData.name)
           console.log(archivos[index].name);
        }
        dispatch(documentAddNew(formData));
    }

    return (
        <div className="container-fluid" id="globalLoad">
            <form className="form-group" encType="multipart/form-data" >
            <h5 className="card-title "> [Cargar en servidor]</h5>
            <label>Selecciona la carpeta de tus PDF</label>
            <div className="input-group mb-3">
            <label className="input-group-text" htmlFor="pdfs">Subir archivos</label>

            <input 
            id="pdfs" 
            type="file" 
            accept="image/*,.pdf" 
            className="form-control" 
            multiple ={true}
            name="archivo" 
            //value={archivos} 
            onChange={(e) => subirArchivos(e.target.files)}
            //webkitdirectory="true"
            />
            <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={insertarArchivos}>Subir Archivos</button>
            </div>
            </form>
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

Accion:

```
//AQUI ARCHIVO [FORMDATA] YA ES UNDEFINED
export const documentAddNew = (archivo) => {
    //Gracias a thunk esto se dispara de nuevo. Si no fuera asincrono, no haria falta el return
    return async () => {
        console.log('Desde accion: ' + toString(archivo.name)); //imprime undefined y Object.FormData
        const reply = await (fetchTokenUpload('upload', archivo, 'POST'));
        const body = reply.json();
        console.log(await body);
        if (body.ok) {
            Swal.fire('Success', "Todo chingon", "success");
        } else {
            Swal.fire('Fallo', "Vuelte a intentar ;)", "error");
        }

    }

}
```

Fetch:

```
const fetchTokenUpload = (endpoint, data, method = "POST") => {

    const url = `${baseURL }/${endpoint}`; 
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token') || '';
    //console.log('Desde Fetch data es: '+ data);
        return fetch(url, {
            method,
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
                'x-api-key': token,
            },
            body: data,
            //body: data,
        });
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es en el fetch, eliminar en los headers el content-type

> sería necesario eliminar `Content-Type` de la petición, caso contrario ignoraría los archivos subidos.

[Respondida aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/236839/error-al-enviar-archivos-con-fetch-en-javascript)

Gracias, buscaba por el lado del console.log en undefined, y hasta esta mañana se me ocurrió buscar en el fetch